# Send to folder like System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient

Tags: c#, mailkit

I'm using MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient and I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to configure this client so that it drop emails to a folder much like in way that the *PickupDirectoryLocation* property affects a System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient dotNet instance.  The need here is for development and debugging so we can safely capture the messages that *would* have gone out.

I'm open to another technique for debugging emails generated by MailKit so long as it does not involve any external services like an SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to do the following:

```
public static void SaveToPickupDirectory (MimeMessage message, string pickupDirectory)
{
    do {
        // Generate a random file name to save the message to.
        var path = Path.Combine (pickupDirectory, Guid.NewGuid ().ToString () + ".eml");
        Stream stream;

        try {
            // Attempt to create the new file.
            stream = File.Open (path, FileMode.CreateNew);
        } catch (IOException) {
        // If the file already exists, try again with a new Guid.
            if (File.Exists (path))
                continue;

            // Otherwise, fail immediately since it probably means that there is
            // no graceful way to recover from this error.
            throw;
        }

        try {
            using (stream) {
                // IIS pickup directories expect the message to be "byte-stuffed"
                // which means that lines beginning with "." need to be escaped
                // by adding an extra "." to the beginning of the line.
                //
                // Use an SmtpDataFilter "byte-stuff" the message as it is written
                // to the file stream. This is the same process that an SmtpClient
                // would use when sending the message in a `DATA` command.
                using (var filtered = new FilteredStream (stream)) {
                    filtered.Add (new SmtpDataFilter ());

                    // Make sure to write the message in DOS (<CR><LF>) format.
                    var options = FormatOptions.Default.Clone ();
                    options.NewLineFormat = NewLineFormat.Dos;

                    message.WriteTo (options, filtered);
                    filtered.Flush ();
                    return;
                }
            }
        } catch {
            // An exception here probably means that the disk is full.
            //
            // Delete the file that was created above so that incomplete files are not
            // left behind for IIS to send accidentally.
            File.Delete (path);
            throw;
        }
    } while (true);
}
```